# closing a cfwindow that uses iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, coldfusion

ISSUE: code that worked to close and destroy a cfwindow after form submit - HAD to be changed to use iFrame (to accommodate file upload). now the 'close' does NOT work.

how does one close a cfwindow that contains an iframe... once the iframe form is submitted????

FLOW:

Base page -> opens window

window contains iframe; iframe -> calls form page

form page -> submit to action page (same page)

action page -> uploads file and does other form processing - closes window.

=====

NOTE: I have reduced the code to the essence - for ease of reading... if blocks of JS need to (or 'should') go elsewhere and be referenced in some other way - please let me know...

## BASE PAGE - basePage.cfm:

```
<script>
    function launchWin(name,url) {
        ColdFusion.Window.create(name+'_formWindow', name, url, 
    {   height:500,
        width:500,
        modal:true,
        closable:true, 
        draggable:true,
        resizable:true,
        center:true,
        initshow:true, 
        minheight:200,
        minwidth:200 
    })
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:launchWin( 'Attachment', 'iframe.cfm?id=101' );" >ATTACH</a>
<DIV ID="myContent"></div>
```

===========================================

## WINDOW PAGE - iframe.cfm - (iframe):

```
<iframe src="attachment.cfm?id=101"></iframe>
```

===========================================

## IFRAME SRC - attachment.cfm (note - this code worked b4 putting it in an iFrame):

```
<script>
ColdFusion.Window.onHide( 'Attachment_formWindow', cleanup );
function cleanup() {
    ColdFusion.Window.destroy( 'Attachment_formWindow', true );
}
</script>


<!--- HANDLE THE FORM --->
<cfif structKeyExists( FORM, 'add_Attachment' )  >
    <!--- Do CFFILE to handle file upload --->
    <cffile action="upload"
            destination="C:\"
            filefield="theFile"
            nameconflict="makeunique">
    <!--- other form processing goes here (not relevant to question at hand) --->
    <!--- refresh the calling page, and close this window - destroy it so contents don't presist --->
    <script>
        ColdFusion.navigate( 'basePage.cfm?', 'myContent' );
        ColdFusion.Window.hide( 'Attachment_formWindow' );
    </script>       
</cfif>


<!--- form to get information --->
<cfform name="attachmentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
<table>
    <tr><td>FILE:</td><td><cfinput type="file" name="theFile" size="40" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>TITLE:</td><td><cfinput type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>DESCRIPTION:</td><td><cftextarea name="description" cols="40" rows="10"></cftextarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><cfinput type="submit" name="add_Attachment" value="Add" /></td></tr>
</table>
</cfform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move code to an iframe, you have to change the references in the javascript to refer to the `parent.`, since the iframe introduces its own child context (vs. a div, which lives within the original context).

Try this:

```
<script>
parent.ColdFusion.Window.onHide( 'Attachment_formWindow', cleanup );
function cleanup() {
    parent.ColdFusion.Window.destroy( 'Attachment_formWindow', true );
}
</script>


<!--- HANDLE THE FORM --->
<cfif structKeyExists( FORM, 'add_Attachment' )  >
    <!--- Do CFFILE to handle file upload --->
    <cffile action="upload"
            destination="C:\"
            filefield="theFile"
            nameconflict="makeunique">
    <!--- other form processing goes here (not relevant to question at hand) --->
    <!--- refresh the calling page, and close this window - destroy it so contents don't presist --->
    <script>
        parent.ColdFusion.navigate( 'basePage.cfm?', 'myContent' );
        parent.ColdFusion.Window.hide( 'Attachment_formWindow' );
    </script>       
</cfif>


<!--- form to get information --->
<cfform name="attachmentForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
<table>
    <tr><td>FILE:</td><td><cfinput type="file" name="theFile" size="40" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>TITLE:</td><td><cfinput type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>DESCRIPTION:</td><td><cftextarea name="description" cols="40" rows="10"></cftextarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><cfinput type="submit" name="add_Attachment" value="Add" /></td></tr>
</table>
</cfform>
```

Comment: Thanks Jake - i could have sworn i tried that...but I must have lost the forest thru the trees. that worked perfectly, and was the exact 'simple' answer I was looking for.